# Do i have to delete my wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

I tried to answer to the question [Number of socks?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/number-of-socks), but I found out that my answer was not only wrong, but far away from correct one.

I don't know if it is better to leave it here as a "hint" for other solvers (even if I think you don't have to peek under spoilers if you want to answer) or delete it since it is a wrong answer (even if they can be considered as a try, and in riddles it can be acceptable).

What do you think?

Comment: I think it is OK to leave it there if you want, but perhaps you could edit in a heading warning the user the answer is actually incorrect.